# How do you install Firefox XPI plugin programmatically in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, firefox-addon, installation, nsis

I have created an NSIS installer to install a USB fingerprint reader software and associated Firefox plugin.

I can install the Firefox XPI plugin I created in WinXP and win7 64 and 32 respectively like this:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions "PSK_plugin@companyname.com" "$INSTDIR\psk.xpi"

WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions "PSK_plugin@companyname.com" "$INSTDIR\psk.xpi"
```

However, the above doesn't work in Windows 8.

Here is the Mozilla link where I discovered the above registry keys. It doesn't include one for Windows 8: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry

Comment: Have you checked if the installer successfully modifies the registry?

Comment: Yup.  It modifies the registry, but the plugin doesn't get installed.  (It does work in xp and 7 with those reg keys)

Comment: You can find out which registry key firefox reads with the help of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (filter is your friend)

Comment: I took a look at Process monitor in win8x64 and then on win7x64.  very similar results.  Both read the reg key.  The only difference is that between reading the reg key and opening the XPI file on win8 it does this a couple of times IRP_MJ_CLOSE C: SUCCESS    I'm going to post the two comparable portions of the log file in the next comment

Comment: it wouldn't let me paste it. Here's a screen cap:  http://i.imgur.com/xHqLT.png

Comment: the only differences appear to be the addition of the 4th and 6th lines in the win8 log file.  BTW the win7 log file has the same RegCloseKey SUCCESS at the end, I just cut it off in my copy.  THANKS VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP SO FAR!  :)  let me know if you have any other suggestions or ideas as to why the plugin is not installing in 8.

Comment: test ok on firfox 28 and windows 8 x64.